# How do you say "billing rate"?

Tags: vocabulario

I've searched for how to translate "billing rate" and "hourly billing rate" into Spanish, but I'm not finding much. One I saw was "tarifa de facturación." Is that good? Are there more or better options. Also, would it make sense to say "tarifa de facturación por hora?" It just seems so long. Something shorter would be great. Target country is Spain, but all comments are welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*tarifas* and *tarificación* are good candidates for a transaltion of *billing rate*.

As for *hourly billing rate*, you could use *precio por hora*

Comment: Tarifa me parece adecuado, pero nunca he escuchado tarificación en lenguaje cotidiano. Pensaria más bien tarifa (billing rate) y tarifa por hora (hourly billing rate).

Comment: So maybe "tarifa de facturacion" is a bit redundant, no? If "tarifa por hora" or "precio por hora" are good, I'll go with one of them.

Comment: *tarifa de facturación* is definitely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Even though *tarifa* is just the amount you charge for a service and can be a one-time payment, it strongly suggests periodicity, so *billing rate* can usually be translated as just *tarifa*. As for *hourly billing rate*, I'd suggest *tarifa horaria*.